# Using xpath to parse out html attributes from webpage

Tags: powershell, xpath, html-parsing

I am having trouble extracting some attributes out of an html page and need some ideas to help me get unstuck.

I am using PowerShell and am using the [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to help me parse the html.  I have a very crude version that I was able to do with regex but it doesn't always work so I thought the better option would be to use xpath to parse the results.  If regex is the way to go please let me know.

So far I have been able to grab the page that I am interested in and split it apart by rows.

```
$results = $htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='row']")
```

After the page is split up I am trying to iterate through each row using xpath to grab the information I am interested in.

```
ForEach ($item in $results) {

$ID=$null

$ID = $item.OuterHtml
}
```

This gets me close to what I am wanting but it grabs a bunch of other info that I don't want as well.  Here is what the $item.outerhml looks like at this point.

```
OuterHtml            : <p class="row" data-latitude="41.5937565437255" data-longitude="-93.6437636649079" data-pid="4184719674"> <a href="/mod/4184719674.html" class="i"></a> 
                   <span class="star"></span> <span class="pl"> <span class="date">Nov 27</span>  <a href="/mod/4184719674.html">iPhone and other Cell Phone Unlocks</a> 
                   </span> <span class="l2">   <span class="pnr"> <small> (Des Moines)</small> <span class="px"> <span class="p"> <a href="#" class="maptag" 
                   data-pid="4184719674">map</a></span></span> </span>  <a class="gc" href="/mod/" data-cat="mod">cell phones - by dealer</a> </span> </p>
```

I just want the data-pid attribute.

[image: sorry for the crappy picture]

I have tried a bunch of other ways to extract the **data-pid** attribute but haven't had any success.  Here is one such method I have tried, but it keeps returning the same value over and over.

```
$ID = $Date.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p/@data-pid")
```

I have a feeling that this is something simple but have hit a roadblock.  Let me know what other information I need to post.

Comment: You have to describe more clearly what _to get stuck_ means. Do you get a compile/syntax error? Do you get a run-time error? Do you get an empty result set?

Comment: I am trying to extract the data-pid attribute for each table row and store it in a variable but I am having trouble getting anything to work.  The code posted above will grab what I need but I am only wanting to get the data-pid attribute from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `foreach` loop you should be able to get the attribute's value like this:

```
$ID = $item.GetAttributeValue("data-pid", "")
```

To walk all the attributes on that node try:

```
$item.Attributes | Select Name,Value
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to use wildcards with this?

Comment: Also, what is the best way to use this for nested tags?  Thanks, so far it is wokring.

Comment: RE wildcards, I don't think so but you can use the Attributes property e.g.: `$item.Attributes | Select Name,Value`.  RE nested tags, you can always use $item.SelectNodes('<xpath query>').

Comment: I will try this out when I get a chance, thanks for the info.

Comment: I'm getting the logic working with my xpath query but it is not working quite right.  I can grab the info I'm interested in but it doesn't iterate through the items the right way.  I can get the correct ID to work but when I try to grab a date it just keeps spitting out the same date.  Should I open a new question or update my original question with details?