# Issue parsing html using powershell and xpath

Tags: html, powershell, xpath, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

This is a follow up question to one I asked last week, [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253722/using-xpath-to-parse-out-html-attributes-from-webpage).  I have gotten past the original issue but now I am running into a slightly different issue.

I am now able to get the attribute of an item I'm interested in if the html tags aren't nested using the GetAttributeValue method, here it is the **data-pid** but I am now having trouble grabbing the attribute of an item that is in nested tags, in my code snippet it is the date.  I am using xpath and the HtmlAgility pack to parse the html here but in the example below the same date gets returned over and over.

Here is what the **$item** object looks like:

```
Attributes           : {class, data-pid}
ChildNodes           : {#text, a, #text, span...}
Closed               : True
ClosingAttributes    : {}
FirstChild           : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlTextNode
HasAttributes        : True
HasChildNodes        : True
HasClosingAttributes : False
Id                   : 
InnerHtml            :  <a href="/mod/4175126893.html" class="i"><span class="price">$20</span></a> <span class="star"></span> <span class="pl"> <span class="date">Nov 
                       30</span>  <a href="/mod/4175126893.html">Unlock Any GSM Cell Phone Today!</a> </span> <span class="l2"> <span class="price">$20</span>  <span 
                       class="pnr"> <small> (Des Moines)</small> <span class="px"> <span class="p"> </span></span> </span>  <a class="gc" href="/mod/" 
                       data-cat="mod">cell phones - by dealer</a> </span> 
InnerText            :  $20   Nov 30  Unlock Any GSM Cell Phone Today!   $20    (Des Moines)      cell phones - by dealer  
LastChild            : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlTextNode
Line                 : 305
LinePosition         : 5408
Name                 : p
NextSibling          : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlTextNode
NodeType             : Element
OriginalName         : p
OuterHtml            : <p class="row" data-pid="4175126893"> <a href="/mod/4175126893.html" class="i"><span class="price">$20</span></a> <span class="star"></span> 
                       <span class="pl"> <span class="date">Nov 30</span>  <a href="/mod/4175126893.html">Unlock Any GSM Cell Phone Today!</a> </span> <span class="l2"> 
                       <span class="price">$20</span>  <span class="pnr"> <small> (Des Moines)</small> <span class="px"> <span class="p"> </span></span> </span>  <a 
                       class="gc" href="/mod/" data-cat="mod">cell phones - by dealer</a> </span> </p>
OwnerDocument        : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
ParentNode           : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
PreviousSibling      : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlTextNode
StreamPosition       : 18733
XPath                : /html[1]/body[1]/article[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[2]/p[11]

Attributes           : {class, data-pid}
ChildNodes           : {#text, a, #text, span...}
Closed               : True
ClosingAttributes    : {}
```

I want to pull out data from the **outerhtml** value.

```
OuterHtml            : <p class="row" data-latitude="41.5937565437255" data-longitude="-93.6437636649079" data-pid="4184719674"> <a href="/mod/4184719674.html" class="i"></a> 
               <span class="star"></span> <span class="pl"> <span class="date">Nov 27</span>  <a href="/mod/4184719674.html">iPhone and other Cell Phone Unlocks</a> 
               </span> <span class="l2">   <span class="pnr"> <small> (Des Moines)</small> <span class="px"> <span class="p"> <a href="#" class="maptag" 
               data-pid="4184719674">map</a></span></span> </span>  <a class="gc" href="/mod/" data-cat="mod">cell phones - by dealer</a> </span> </p>
```

I can grab the **data-pid** no problem.  Here is what the current code looks like:

```
ForEach ($item in $results) {

    # This is working
    $ID = $item.GetAttributeValue("data-pid", "")

    # This is looping over the same item
    $Date = $item.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='date']").InnerText
}
```

What I want to do is to be able to grab attributes from the different tags that are contained in the outerhtml object using my xpath statements but I can't figure out how to do that.  Is that the best way to go about the problem or should I just be using some regex to get the value I want?

Let me know what other details I need to post.

Comment: > Any copying, aggregation, display, distribution, performance or derivative use of craigslist or any content posted on craigslist whether done directly or through intermediaries (including but not limited to by means of spiders, robots, crawlers, scrapers, framing, iframes or RSS feeds) is prohibited.

([Source](http://www.craigslist.org/about/terms.of.use))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't used the HTML Agility Pack, but AFAICS built-in tools should suffice anyway:

```ps
$url = 'http://www.example.com/path/to/some.html'

$html = (Invoke-Webrequest $url).ParsedHTML

$html.getElementsByTagName('p') | ? { $_.className -eq 'row' } | % {
  $ID   = $_.getAttributeNode('data-pid').value
  $Date = $_.getElementsByTagName('span') | ? { $_.className -eq 'date' } |
          % { $_.innerText }

  # do stuff with $ID and $Date
  "{0}: {1}" -f $ID, $Date
}
```

Note that `Invoke-Webrequest` requires PowerShell v3. Use the Internet Explorer COM object if your limited to PowerShell v2:

```ps
$ie = New-Object -COM InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate($url)
while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) { sleep 100 }
$html = $ie.Document
```

If your HTML file is a local file, replace the `Invoke-Webrequest` line with something like this:

```ps
$htmlfile = 'C:\path\to\some.html'

$html = New-Object -COM HTMLFile
$html.write((Get-Content $htmlfile | Out-String))
```

Comment: So far this is working for me but it is taking forever to run.  Do you know what would cause it to take such a long time?

Comment: Without knowing the actual input data you're running this on? Hardly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm way too late but here's your mistake. You've been using absolute paths.

```ps
ForEach ($item in $results) {

    # This is working
    $ID = $item.GetAttributeValue("data-pid", "")

    # This is looping over the same item
    $Date = $item.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='date']").InnerText

    # This is looping over the different items (i.e. this is what what you want)
    $Date = $item.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='date']").InnerText
}
```